# Perturbation Methods-Multiscale expansions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I was looking at some of the problems from the chapter Multiple-scale expansion in Introduction to Perturbation Methods by Mark H. Holmes. I came across this question to find the first term expansion:

$\epsilon y''+\epsilon y'+y=cos(t)$, where 
$y(0)=0=y'(0)$. I took my slow and fast scale variables as $t_1=t$ and $t_2=\sqrt{\epsilon}t$. My question arises when we have to find the $O(1)$ expansion of the term.I'm aware that I need to use Taylors expansion, but something doesn't seem to fit quiet properly. 
 It would be great if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: What section is this example from and what is the stated aim this example is to demonstrate? What is the approach discussed in that section?

Comment: This is from Chapter 3, Multiple Scales method, Section 3.2, question 3.1(a). The question asks us to find the first term expansion.@LutzL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should get an approximation for is depicted in the following plot of numerical solutions for some perturbation parameters.
[image: numerical solutions]
This picture corresponds to some extended understanding of *"boundary layer"*, as there is indeed some rapid compensation for the gap between the value $1$ at $t=0$ of the *outer solution* $y_{\rm outer}(t)=\cos(t)$ and the initial condition $y(0)=0$. This first segment has indeed also a width of $\sim\sqrt{ϵ}$, but then overshoots the outer solution and oscillates with frequency $1/\sqrt{ϵ}$, dampened by the friction term containing the first derivative giving a uniform hull curve for the amplitude of the oscillation of $e^{-t/2}$. Taking these building blocks to first satisfy $y(0)=0$ and then also $y'(0)=0$ gives the first order approximation
$$
y(t)\approx \cos(t)-e^{-t/2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{ϵ}}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{ϵ}}2\sin\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{ϵ}}\right)\right)
$$

Let's be a bit more ingeniuous about it. We know that largely $y(t)=\cos(t)+u(t)$ where $u$ will be small in later times. But then
$$
ϵu''+ϵu'+u=ϵ\cos(t)+ϵ\sin(t)
$$
Adjust the decomposition of $y$ for the new right side, now $y(t)=(1+ϵ)\cos(t)+ϵ\sin(t)+u(t)$, then the differential equation reads
$$
\begin{split}
ϵ[-(1+ϵ)\cos(t)-ϵ\sin(t)+u''(t)]&+ϵ[-(1+ϵ)\sin(t)+ϵ\cos(t)+u(t)]\\&+[(1+ϵ)\cos(t)+ϵ\sin(t)+u(t)]=\cos(t)
\end{split}
\\\iff\\
ϵu''+ϵu'+u=2ϵ^2\sin(t)\iff u''+u'+\frac1ϵu=2ϵ\sin(t)
$$
which now is essentially a homogeneous equation.

### Approach via parametrized sinusoid

As this is a harmonic oscillator with damping, use the form proposed in the hint at the end of the section, set $u(t)=A(t)\cos(ωt+θ(t))$ with $ω=\sqrt{\frac1ϵ}$ and  $A(t),θ(t)$ "slow" moving, in the sense that their derivatives are small against $ω$. Then
\begin{align}
u'(t)&=A'(t)\cos(ωt+θ(t))-A(t)\sin(ωt+θ(t))(ω+θ'(t))  \\
u''(t)&=A''(t)\cos(ωt+θ(t))-2A'(t)\sin(ωt+θ(t))(ω+θ'(t))  \\
& ~ ~ ~ ~- A(t)\cos(ωt+θ(t))(ω+θ'(t))^2-A(t)\sin(ωt+θ(t))θ''(t)  \\
\end{align}
Comparing coefficients in $u''(t)+u'(t)+ω^2u(t)$ results in the identies
\begin{align}
0&=A''(t)+A'(t)- A(t)(2ω+θ'(t))θ'(t)\\
0&=-A(t)θ''(t)-2A'(t)(ω+θ'(t)) -A(t)(ω+θ'(t))\\[.7em]
\implies 
2A(t)θ'(t)&=\sqrt{ϵ}[A''(t)+A'(t)-2A(t)θ'(t)^2]\\
2A'(t)+A(t)&=-\sqrt{ϵ}[A(t)θ''(t)+ (2A'(t)+A(t))θ'(t)]
\end{align}
so that in first approximation $A(t)=A_0e^{-t/2}$ and $θ(t)=θ_0$. Inserting into the right side gives the next order of approximation as 
\begin{align}
2θ'(t)&=\sqrt{ϵ}[\tfrac14-\tfrac12]&&\implies& θ(t)=θ_0-\frac{\sqrt{ϵ}}8t\\
2A'(t)+A(t)&=0&&\implies& \text{unchanged}
\end{align}

---

Now adjust the coefficients for the initial conditions in 
\begin{align}
y(t)&=(1+ϵ)\cos(t)+ϵ\sin(t)+A_0e^{-t/2}\cos\left((ω-\tfrac18\sqrt{ϵ})t+θ_0\right)\\
y'(t)&=-(1+ϵ)\sin(t)+ϵ\cos(t)-\tfrac12 A_0e^{-t/2}\cos\left((ω-\tfrac18\sqrt{ϵ})t+θ_0\right)
\\&~~~~-(ω-\tfrac18\sqrt{ϵ})A_0e^{-t/2}\sin\left((ω-\tfrac18\sqrt{ϵ})t+θ_0\right)
\\\hline
0=y(0)&=(1+ϵ)+A_0\cos\left(θ_0\right)\\
0=y'(0)&=ϵ-\tfrac12 A_0\cos\left(θ_0\right)-(ω-\tfrac18\sqrt{ϵ})A_0\sin\left(θ_0\right)\\
&=\tfrac12(1+3ϵ)-ω(1-\tfrac18ϵ)A_0\sin\left(θ_0\right)
\end{align}
It remains to solve the polar decomposition $A_0(\cos(θ_0),\sin(θ_0))=(-(1+ϵ), \tfrac12\sqrtϵ+O(ϵ^{3/2}))$ giving $θ_0=\pi-\tfrac12\sqrtϵ$ and $A_0=1+\frac98ϵ$.

---

### Approach via WKB approximation

This all follows much more easily if the basis functions are computed via a *WKB expansion* $u(t)=e^{S/\delta}$, allowing for complex exponents, and then the real combinations are taken. The equation $ϵu''+ϵu'+u=0$ then leads to
$$
ϵ(δS''+S'^2)+ϵδS'+δ^2=0
$$
Also here one finds balancing for $δ^2=ϵ$ so that
$$
S'^2+1=-δ(S''+S')
$$
Using an expansion in powers of $δ$ (and setting $s_k=S_k'$) gives $s_0=\pm i$, $2s_0s_1=-s_0\implies s_1=-\frac12$, $s_1^2+2s_0s_2=-s_1\implies s_2=\mp\frac{i}8$
so that the basis solutions up to that approximation order are in their real form
$$
y_1(t)=e^{-t/2}\cos\left(\left(\frac1δ-\fracδ8\right)t\right),~~
y_2(t)=e^{-t/2}\sin\left(\left(\frac1δ-\fracδ8\right)t\right).
$$
Now use shortly $ω=\left(\frac1δ-\fracδ8\right)=\sqrt{\frac1ϵ}(1-\fracϵ8)$ and match the initial conditions for
\begin{align}
y(t)&=(1+ϵ)\cos(t)+ϵ\sin(t)+e^{-t/2}[A_0\cos(ωt)+B_0\sin(ωt)]\\
y'(t)&=-(1+ϵ)\sin(t)+ϵ\cos(t)-\tfrac12 e^{-t/2}[A_0\cos(ωt)+B_0\sin(ωt)]-ωe^{-t/2}[A_0\sin(ωt)-B_0\cos(ωt)]
\\\hline
0=y(0)&=(1+ϵ)+A_0\\
0=y'(0)&=ϵ-\tfrac12 A_0+ωB_0=\tfrac12(1+3ϵ)+ωB_0
\end{align}
so that more directly $A_0=-(1+ϵ)$ and $B_0=-\tfrac12\sqrtϵ(1+O(ϵ))$.

With some slightly more computation one can get also the next terms in the expansions of $A_0,B_0$

Comment: We're actually supposed to use the multiple scale method, which is why I took $t_1=t$ and $t_2=\sqrt(\epsilon)t$. @LutzL

Comment: Ok, with the hint given at the end of the section, you are to use $y(t)=A(ϵ,t)\cos(t/\sqrtϵ+\theta(ϵ,t))$ which in the main will replicate the steps and results of the WKB approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Lutzl's answers is excellent, but I wanted to add the direct multiple-scales version.

Let $t_1=t$ and $t_2=\epsilon^\alpha t$, and $y(t)=Y(t_1,t_2)$. Substituting into the differential equation gives

$$ \epsilon Y_{t_1t_2}+2\epsilon^{1+\alpha}Y_{t_1t_2}+\epsilon^{1+2\alpha}Y_{t_2t_2}+\epsilon Y_{t_1}+\epsilon^{1+\alpha}Y_{t_2}+Y=\cos(t_1). $$

If we pick $\alpha>0$ then the leading order equation will be $Y_0=\cos(t_1)$ which doesn't satisfy the initial conditions, so we must have $\alpha<0$ and hence $\alpha=-1/2$ by dominant balance (this was your error, you had $\alpha=1/2$). So the system to solve is
$$ \epsilon Y_{t_1t_2}+2\epsilon^{1/2}Y_{t_1t_2}+Y_{t_2t_2}+\epsilon Y_{t_1}+\epsilon^{1/2}Y_{t_2}+Y=\cos(t_1)\quad Y(0,0)=0,\quad \epsilon^{1/2}Y_{t_1}(0,0)+Y_{t_2}(0,0)=0. $$

Expand $Y$ as $Y_0+\epsilon^{1/2}Y_1+\ldots$ to give, at leading order,

$$ Y_{0,t_2t_2}+Y_{0}=\cos(t_1),\quad Y_0(0,0)=0,\quad Y_{0,t_2}(0,0)=0, $$
with solution $Y_0=A(t_1)\cos(t_2)+B(t_1)\sin(t_2)+\cos(t_1)$, where $A(0)+1=0$ and $B(0)=0$ to satisfy the initial conditions.

The $O(\epsilon^{1/2})$ equation is

$$ Y_{1,t_2t_2}+Y_{1}=-2Y_{0,t_1t_2}-Y_{0,t_2},\quad Y_1(0,0)=0,\quad Y_{0,t_1}+Y_{1,t_2}(0,0)=0, $$
and substituting $Y_0$, 
$$ Y_{1,t_2t_2}+Y_{1}=(2A'(t_1)+A(t_1))\sin(t_2)-(2B'(t_1)+B(t_1))\cos(t_2). $$
The $\sin(t_2)$ and $\cos(t_2)$ terms are secular, so we must remove them by setting 
$$ 2A'+A=0,\quad 2B'+B=0 $$
which, coupled with the initial conditions $A(0)=-1$ and $B(0)=0$, give $A(t_1)=-e^{-t_1/2}$ and $B(t_1)=0$.

So we finally get $$ Y_0(t_1,t_2) = -e^{-t_1/2}\cos(t_2)+\cos(t_1) $$
or, in terms of $y$ and $t$,
$$y(t)=-e^{-t/2}\cos\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\right)+\cos(t)+O(\sqrt{\epsilon}).$$

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing my doubt!

Comment: If we take $\alpha=-1/2$ then wouldn't we have to get $O(\frac{1}{\sqrt\epsilon}) $instead?

Comment: Also, another question that I have is the asymptotic expansion of $Y$ as $ Y_0+\epsilon^{1/2}Y_1$.. how exactly do you get this, cause the expansion I know take $\epsilon$ to the power 1. @David

Comment: There are two separate scaling arguments. One is for the time scales, which are $O(\epsilon^{-1/2})$ and $O(1)$. The other is for the asymptotic expansion for $Y$. You can do a dominant balance argument to determine the powers, but in this case the simple thing $Y_0+\sqrt{\epsilon}Y_1+\epsilon Y_2+\ldots$ works. Since the equation has $\sqrt{\epsilon}$ terms, I guessed that the expansion for $Y$ should also include half-powers of $\epsilon$.

Comment: okay.. But the final one term expansion that is obtained at $Y(t)$ doesn't satisfy the boundary condition at $Y'(t)$.

Comment: Yes. The $Y_1$ term corrects the error though. The initial condition $y'(0)=0$ has leading-order term $O(\epsilon^{-1/2})$, and $Y_0$ satisfies that, but leaves an $O(1)$ error behind, which is corrected by $Y_1$, and so on. The initial condition is satisfied one order lower in $\sqrt{\epsilon}$ than the reset of the problem. I think that's just the way it is.

Comment: okay! Sorry to trouble you with so many questions. The system can't be solved right if we use the time scale at $O(\sqrt\epsilon)$?

Comment: That would correspond to a very slow time scale. Lutzl's answer explains quite well why there is a fast ($1/\sqrt{\epsilon}$) time scale and an $O(1)$ time scale. An $O(\sqrt{\epsilon})$ time scale would correspond to very slow changes, but we know