# Solve $x''+x=\epsilon x^2$ as $\epsilon\to0$ using the Poincaré-Lindstedt method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

I'm self studying some asymptotic techniques to deal with my engineering problems.
Given $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+x=\epsilon x^2,~x(0)=1,~x'(0)=0$. I want to use the Poincaré-Lindstedt method to solve it as $\epsilon\to0$. First I let $x(t)=X(t)$ and $\theta=\Omega(\epsilon)t$, $\Omega(0)=\omega_0$.
Then I have $$\Omega^2\frac{d^2X}{d\theta^2}+X=\epsilon X^2,~X(0)=1,~\Omega\left.\frac{dX}{d\theta}\right\vert_{\theta=0}=0$$

Expand $X=X_0(\theta)+\epsilon X_1(\theta)+\epsilon^2X_2(\theta)+\cdots$. Then I have

$$\Omega^2\left(X_0''(\theta)+\epsilon X_1''(\theta)+\epsilon^2X_2''(\theta)+\cdots\right)+\left(X_0(\theta)+\epsilon X_1(\theta)+\epsilon^2X_2(\theta)+\cdots\right)=\epsilon\left(X_0(\theta)+\epsilon X_1(\theta)+\epsilon^2X_2(\theta)+\cdots\right)^2$$

However, I don't know how to keep going. The reference I am using did some strange steps in collecting the $O(\epsilon^1)$ terms, which make me confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to insert the expansion of $Ω(ϵ)=1+ϵΩ_1+ϵ^2Ω_2+...$ so that you get
$$
(1+2ϵΩ_1+..)(X_0''+ϵX_1''+..)+(X_0+ϵX_1+...)=ϵ(X_0^2+2ϵX_0X_1+...)
$$
Comparing coefficients then gives in the first two orders of $ϵ$
$$
X_0''+X_0=0\\
2Ω_1X_0''+X_1''+X_1=X_0^2\\
$$
As $X_0^2$ will have frequencies $0$ and $2$, there are no secular terms to compensate, so set $Ω_1=0$. Then in the $ϵ^2$ terms you get
$$
2Ω_2X_0''+X_2''+X_2=2X_0X_1\\
$$
The product $X_0X_1$ consist of terms with frequencies $2\pm1$ and $0+1$, so there will be secular terms of frequency $1$ that can be compensated by the $X_0''$ term, giving $Ω_2$ a non-zero value.

---

In detail, $X_0=\cos(θ)$, resulting in $X_0^2=\frac12(1+\cos(2θ)$, which gives per "undetermined coefficients"
$$X_1=A(1-\cos(θ))+B(\cos(2θ)-\cos(θ)),$$
with $A=\frac12$ and $-3B=\frac12$.
Now
$$
2X_0X_1=\frac12(2\cosθ-1-\cos(2θ))-\frac16(\cos(3θ)+\cosθ-1-\cos(2θ))
$$
thus $-2Ω_2=1-\frac16=\frac56$.

Comment: Thanks! It's pretty clear. Btw, do you know what books in asymptotic analysis are clear and are recommended?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3370184/perturbation-methods-multiscale has a book by H. Holmes, which is also cited in other places.