# Poincaré-Lindstedt method for $x'' + x = \epsilon x^2$ for the $x_1$ equation as $\epsilon \to 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

My question is in the last step of the post [Solve $x''+x=\epsilon x^2$ as $\epsilon\to0$ using the Poincaré-Lindstedt method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4152781/solve-xx-epsilon-x2-as-epsilon-to0-using-poincare-lindstedt) which outlines how the expansion is set up and the $x_0 = \cos(\theta)$ is derived.

If $x(s,\epsilon) = x_0(s) + \epsilon x_1(s) + \epsilon^2 x_2(s) + ...$ then equating the coefficients in the same way as the post, I get $x_0(s) = \cos(s)$ and the differential equation setup for $x_1$.

$\frac{d^2x_1}{ds^2}+ x_1(x) = 2\omega_1\cos(s) + \cos^2(s) = 2\omega_1\cos(s) + \frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(2s))$

What I am lost about is where the intuition for the solution of the $x_1$ is $A(1-\cos(s)) + B(\cos(2s) - \cos(s)$ comes from.

Derivation of the equations:

$\omega = \omega_0 + \epsilon\omega_1 + \epsilon^2\omega_2 + ...$

$x(s, \epsilon) = x_0(s) + \epsilon x_1(s) + \epsilon^2 x_2(s) + ...$

$\frac{d^2 x}{ds^2} = \frac{d^2 x_0}{ds^2} + \epsilon \frac{d^2 x_1}{ds^2} + \epsilon^2 \frac{d^2 x_2}{ds^2} + ...$

In the form of the differential equation,

$\omega^2\frac{d^2 x}{ds^2} + x = \epsilon x^2 \implies $

$(\omega_0 + \epsilon \omega_1 + \epsilon^2\omega_2+...)^2(\frac{d^2x_0}{ds^2} + \epsilon \frac{d^2x_1}{ds^2} + \epsilon^2 \frac{d^2x_2}{ds^2} + ...) + x_0 +\epsilon x_1 + ... = \epsilon(x_0 + \epsilon x_1 + ...)^2$

For the $\epsilon^0$:

$\omega_0^2 \frac{d^2x_0}{ds^2} + x_0 = 0 \implies x_0 = \cos(\frac{s}{\omega_0})$ and by the periodicity condition $x_0(s+2\pi) = x_0(s)$ $\omega_0 = 1$.

For the $\epsilon^1$:

$2\omega_0\omega_1\frac{d^2x_0}{ds^2} + \omega_0^2\frac{d^2x_1}{ds^2} + x_1 = x_0^2$. For the secular terms from 0 and 2 frequencies respectively, $\omega_1 = 0$ must be true.

This simplifies to the equation above, $\frac{d^2 x_1}{ds^2} + x_1 = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \cos(2s)$

Help is appreciated

Comment: Take the second derivative to check.

Comment: I get that its a valid solution, but is there some intuition for where this comes from? It seems too specific to guess.

Comment: Goncalo already found one typo which you haven't yet corrected. Talking about intuition here is another potential problem: I find it hard to believe that the solution does not depend on $\omega_1\,.$ You should probably show us your steps of checking the solution.

Comment: I was unable to ask in the comment section of his answer and was not able to send any direct messages, which resulted in the creation of this post. The scaling of the $\cos^2(s) = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \cos(2s)$ has been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can multiply the equation with $2x'$ and integrate to get a first integral that has bounded level sets around the origin. This gives raise to closed orbits and periodic solutions.

It is expected that the period will also depend on $\epsilon$, therefore one tries the solution form $x(t)=C(\omega(\epsilon)t,\epsilon)$. The first argument of $C$ or the product inside gets the name $\theta$, and by abuse of notation $C$ is replaced with $x$, even though it is now a different function. This way one gets
$$
x''(s)=\omega(\epsilon)^2\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial\theta^2}.
$$
It is $C(\theta,\epsilon)$ that gets expanded as $x_0(\theta)+\epsilon x_1(\theta)+...$ which leads to the mentioned detailed equation
\begin{multline}
(1+ϵω_1+ϵ^2ω_2+...)^2(x_0''(θ)+ϵ x_1''(θ)+ϵ^2 x_2''(θ)+...)\\+(x_0(θ)+ϵ x_1(θ)+ϵ^2 x_2(θ)+...)\\=ϵ(x_0(θ)+ϵ x_1(θ)+ϵ^2 x_2(θ)+...)^2
\end{multline}
and by comparing coefficients to the system
\begin{align}
x_0''(θ)+x_0(θ)&=0\\
2ω_1x_0''+(x_1''+x_1)&=x_0^2\\
(2ω_2+ω_1^2)x_0''+ω_1x_1''+(x_2''+x_2)&=2x_0x_1
\end{align}
etc. So one finds $x_0(θ)=\cos(θ)$.

The aim is to fix the parameters and component functions to avoid non-periodic resonance terms as one would get from $2ω_1x_0$ in the second equation. So set $ω_1=0$. Thus remains
$$
x_1''(θ)+x_1(θ)=x_0(θ)^2=\frac12(1+\cos(2θ))
$$
From the method of undetermined coefficients the general solution form is known as
$$
x_1(θ)=A+B\cos(2θ)+C\cos(θ)+D\sin(θ)
$$
Now one can reduce the system by directly satisfying the homogeneous initial conditions $x_1(0)=x_1'(0)=0$ by shifting some amount from the complementary solution to the particular solution
$$
x_1(θ)=A(1-\cos(θ))+B(\cos(2θ)-\cos(θ))
$$
Inserting into the DE results in $A=\frac12$, $-3B=\frac12$.

---

In the third equation one can replace $x_0''$ with $-x_0$ to get
\begin{align}
x_2''+x_2&=2ω_2x_0+2x_0x_1\\&=(2ω_2+1-\tfrac16)\cos(θ)-\tfrac16(1+\cos(2θ))-\tfrac1{6}\cos(3θ)
\end{align}
Thus $ω_2=-\frac5{12}$ to avoid non-periodic resonance terms and so on.

Comment: This clears up a lot, I needed to see some more of the computational steps!